# Adding JSON file to plugin qmake project

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

When writing plugin libraries with Qt one can attach a JSON file containing some meta data to it using the `Q_PLUGIN_METADATA` macro. This JSON file is then linked into the library, for later usage with `QPluginLoader::metaData()`.

Unfortunately when building the plugin library the associated JSON file is not by default seen as a dependency for the library binary by `qmake`. When the JSON file is modified the plugin library project has to be rebuild (especially re-linked) manually to force the modified JSON file into the library binary.

What would be the proper way to mention the JSON file in the `.pro` file so that it is automatically linked in when it is modified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically use the following to make the json file a dependency of the generated moc file that contains the corresponding code. Assuming the class where you specify `Q_PLUGIN_METADATA` is located in a header file called `myclass.h`, the qmake code is as follows:

```
DISTFILES += myclass.json
json_target.target = moc_myclass.o
json_target.depends += $$PWD/myclass.json
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += json_target
```

**Note:** You might have to use `json_target.target = $$OBJECTS_DIR/moc_myclass.o` instead, if OBJECTS_DIR has previously been defined. Check the generated `Makefile` to see if the path of the dependency matches the one of the corresponding target.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Well, you could just add the JSON file to resources: create some `*.qrc` file, add yours there and then write in the `.pro` file something like `RESOURCES += plugin_data.qrc`.-
There is also `DISTFILES` variable, but AFAIK it's Unix-only and does not solve your problem.</s>

Tried myself and it never worked, still the recipe from documentation works: `INCLUDEPATH += JSON_FILE_LOCATION_DIR`. It's true that `qmake` caches builds sometimes, but they say adding to include path should do the trick and make a proper build.